# pointer typecasting

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
int *p,*q;
p=(int *)1000;
q=(int *)2000;
printf("%d:%d:%d",q,p,(q-p));
}
```

output

```
2000:1000:250
```

1.I cannot understand `p=(int *)1000;` line, does this mean that p is pointing to 1000 address location? what if I do `*p=22` does this value is stored at 1000 address and overwrite the existing value? If it overwrites the value, what if another program is working with 1000 address space?

1. how `q-p=250`?

**EDIT:**  I tried `printf("%u:%u:%u",q,p,(q-p));` the output is the same

```
int main()
{
int *p;
int i=5;
p=&i;
printf("%u:%d",p,i);
return 0;
}
```

the output

```
3214158860:5
```

1. does this mean the addresses used by compiler are integers? there is no difference between normal integers and address integers?

Comment: why downvote?plz explain. I think i should not accept any answers unless i get explanation for downvotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> does this mean that p is pointing to 1000 address location?

Yes.

> what if I do *p=22

It's invoking undefined behavior - your program will most likely crash with a segfault.

Note that in modern OSes, addresses are virtual - you can't overwrite an other process' adress space like this, but you can attempt writing to an invalid memory location in your own process' address space.

> how q-p=250?

Because pointer arithmetic works like this (in order to be compatible with array indexing). The difference of two pointers is the difference of their value divided by `sizeof(*ptr)`. Similarly, adding `n` to a pointer `ptr` of type `T` results in a numeric value `ptr + n * sizeof(T)`.

[Read this on pointers.](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html)

> does this mean the addresses used by compiler are integers?

That "used by compiler" part is not even necessary. Addresses *are* integers, it's just an abstraction in C that we have nice pointers to ease our life. If you were coding in assembly, you would just treat them as unsigned integers.

By the way, writing

```
printf("%u:%d", p, i);
```

is also undefined behavior - the `%u` format specifier expects an `unsigned int`, and not a pointer. To print a pointer, use `%p`:

```
printf("%p:%d", (void *)p, i);
```

Comment: what if I do p=(int *)1; the output is 1 offcourse but, what i want to understand is how does the compiler handle this

Comment: @BhavikShah Well, it compiles it, what other kind of "handling" do you expect?

Comment: one last question. where do you get these specifications about undefined behaviour?

Comment: @BhavikShah from the Standard.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with `*p=22` you write to 1000 address.

`q-p` is 250 because size of int is 4 so it's 2000-1000/4=250

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of `p = (int *) 1000` is implementation-defined. But yes, in a typical implementation it will make `p` to point to address `1000`.

Doing `*p = 22` afterwards will indeed attempt to store `22` at address `1000`. However, in general case this attempt will lead to undefined behavior, since you are not allowed to just write data to arbitrary memory locations. You have to allocate memory in one way or another in order to be able to use it. In your example you didn't make any effort to allocate anything at address `1000`. This means that most likely your program will simply crash, because it attempted to write data to a memory region that was not properly allocated. (Additionally, on many platforms in order to access data through pointers these pointers must point to properly *aligned* locations.)

Even if you somehow succeed succeed in writing your `22` at address `1000`, it does not mean that it will in any way affect "other programs". On some old platforms it would (like DOS, fro one example). But modern platforms implement independent virtual memory for each running program (process). This means that each running process has its own separate address `1000` and it cannot see the other program's address `1000`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, `p` is pointing to virtual address 1000.  If you use `*p = 22;`, you are likely to get a segmentation fault; quite often, the whole first 1024 bytes are invalid for reading or writing.  It can't affect another program assuming you have virtual memory; each program has its own virtual address space.
2. The value of `q - p` is the number of units of `sizeof(*p)` or `sizeof(*q)` or `sizeof(int)` between the two addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Casting arbitrary integers to pointers is undefined behavior. Anything can happen including nothing, a segmentation fault or silently overwriting other processes' memory (unlikely in the modern virtual memory models).

But we used to use absolute addresses like this back in the real mode DOS days to access interrupt tables and BIOS variables :)

About `q-p == 250`, it's the result of semantics of pointer arithmetic. Apparently `sizeof int` is 4 in your system. So when you add 1 to an int pointer it actually gets incremented by 4 so it points to the next `int` not the next byte. This behavior helps with array access.

Answer (score -1):

```
does this mean that p is pointing to 1000 address location?
```

yes. But this 1000 address may belong to some other processes address.In this case, You illegally accessing the memory of another process's address space. This may results in segmentation fault.

Comment: That address belonging to another process's address space is extremely unlikely outside of embedded OS with no virtual memory. Plus the code above doesn't dereference the pointers, so it's not accessing that address.

Comment: `what if I do *p=22 does this value is stored at 1000 address and overwrite the existing value?` asked by OP. @Mat, Pls read the question clearly.

Comment: you're not explaining that part correctly given my previous comment. And you haven't addressed the pointer subtraction.

Comment: k leave it @Mat. I spent my time by commenting instead of answering.. :)